# withoutOverlapping() is not working in Laravel Schedule, when i set CACHE_DRIVER=array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, schedule

Laravel version 5.5.0 
php version 7.1.14

set CACHE_DRIVER=array in .env

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
    $schedule->command('test:write_log')->name('WriteLog')->withoutOverlapping();
 }
```

When I run my schedule, the withoutOverlapping is not working as expected.
And I does not see the schedule-xxxxxx file. 
But if I change the CACHE_DRIVER to file. It works.(also doesn't see the schedule-xxxxx file)

Comment: It's a good question